# Unable to install online apps on Wine

Tags: 16.04, wine, ufw, winetricks, google-drive

Wine is working perfectly well with off-line installers. But with on-line installers such as Google Backup & Sync and Tally (which is an ERP software), it is displaying an error.

[Google Backup and Sync screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvKmr.png)

```
0138:fixme:winhttp:WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl discovery via DHCP not supported
```

[Tally screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6tT7.png)

```
0026:err:ole:start_rpcss failed to start RpcSs service
0009:err:wininet:open_http_connection create_netconn failed: 12029
```

On the other hand, applications that have already been installed using offline installers, are later having no troubles connecting with the internet.

I have tried:

disabling the firewall using

```
sudo ufw disable
```

installing winhttp dll using winetricks

```
winetricks winhttp
```

and in wincfg libraries, adding "dbghelp" and removing "d3d11".

Have also tried different Windows Versions in winecfg.

I'd prefer to fix this issue, rather than look for alternatives like Grive or offline installers.